# Is the private data safe to take to a service center if the HDD is locked with BitLocker?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, bitlocker

I have a laptop which I need to take to a service center (cooler needs to be changed).

The problem is that I have private data on the HDD inside the laptop.

#### If I protect it with BitLocker, then is it safe to be taken to the service center?

Hypotetically speaking, could that protection be somehow bypassed / cracked (eg. with the HDD physically taken out of the laptop, connected to a different PC, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

Send your laptop in with a different/blank hard drive in it with a fresh install of windows on it and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

With Bitlocker it should be safe, but:

1. service can reformat and install clean Windows on it, what usually service does
2. you should make a backup of all your data, for example on external drive
3. it is possible that service will exchange the whole laptop - what then?
4. it makes difference if this is original service for laptop, or just local and not related

Comment: I plan to take the laptop for a cooler change, **and** give them an ubuntu stick to boot-up just in case. They'd better **not** format the laptop... :)

Comment: @Serban Having backups is always your responsibility. Service is never responsible for keeping your data.

Answer (score -1):

If you have set a preboot-PIN (as in: laptop does only start booting after the correct Bitlocker PIN is typed), then it's very safe. If there's no PIN requested, it's moderately safe as in "guys with skills can decrypt it".

You may set a PIN like this: https://www.howtogeek.com/262720/how-to-enable-a-pre-boot-bitlocker-pin-on-windows/

Comment: So I guess the whole `"guys with skills can decrypt it"` thing is still valid if _the guys_ take the HDD out of the laptop and connect it to a different machine, right ?

Comment: @Serban - If you attach a BitLocker encrypted system drive to another system you need the BitLocker recovery key to mount the drive

Comment: Yes, Ramhound is right, taking it out would make it harder to crack (much, much harder), not easier. So, please answer: did you set up a PIN, yet? You should, so you don't have to worry.

Comment: The thing is: I would like the laptop to still be bootable (eg: from an ubuntu usb-stick). I'm not afraid of the "guys with skills can decrypt it", I only have some private data with no value for anybody else and I'm not wanted by spy agencies :) . 
So... without the `pre-boot pin`, how does the BitLocker protection work ? What other kind of pin is there, when do I get prompted for it ?

Comment: The ubuntu USB stick does not care for bitlocker, it works. Set a PIN. If security ain't that important, don't bother with a PIN. But as long as the windows on the device is bootable, someone can attack it. Without a PIN, it works with a TPM protector. In short: when starting the device, it looks as it's unencrypted. When starting a boot stick, the drive is inaccessible nevertheless, unless you can present the 48-digit bitlocker recovery key. However, if the logon prompt can be overcome (guessable or no password), attackers can get in. With a PIN, they can't even boot windows (but Ubuntu).